# I can't login as user in my website after changing the data from the back to the MongoDb atlas

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, mongodb-atlas

I changed the product and user data to mongoDb atlas the product does exist in the website and working just fine but when it come to login with the user data , i put the the correct account email and pass , he tell me that i'm connect successfully but doesn't actually log me in the account (profile) in the website

user model :

```
import {Schema, model} from 'mongoose';

export interface User{
    id:string;
    email:string;
    password: string;
    name:string;
    address:string;
    isAdmin:boolean;
}

export const UserSchema = new Schema<User>({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, required: true},
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON:{
        virtuals: true
    },
    toObject:{
        virtuals: true
    }
});

export const UserModel = model<User>('user', UserSchema);
```

User router :

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { sample_users } from "../data";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import { UserModel } from "../models/user.model";


const router = Router();
  

router.get("/seed", asyncHandler(
  async (req, res) => {
     const usersCount = await UserModel.countDocuments();
     if(usersCount> 0){
       res.send("Seed is already done!");
       return;
     }
 
     await UserModel.create(sample_users);
     res.send("Seed Is Done!");
 }
 ))

 router.post("/login", asyncHandler(
  async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email,password });

    if (user) {
      res.send(generateTokenResponse(user));
    } 
    else {
      const BAD_REQUEST=400
      res.status(BAD_REQUEST).send("Username or password is not valid");
    }
  }
));


const generateTokenResponse = (user: any) => {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      email: user.email,

      isAdmin: user.isAdmin
    },
    "SomeRandomText",
    {
      expiresIn: "30d"
    }
  );

  user.token = token;
  return user;
};

export default router ;
```

I couldn't find any problem in the code
The user data is does exist and connected to mongoDB and mongoDB is connect to the website , but why i can't login with that data in my website ?